# Date formatting with date_format

Tags: php, date, date-format

I have a small events script I wrote to suite my client.
The script work perfect but I cannot get the date to display, example:

```
25 August 2015
```

My question comes not for the lack of searching Stack Overflow and other resources.

The date format straight from MySQL:

```
echo  $row['date_start'];  //2015-08-26
```

How I want it to be:

```
25 August 2015
```

And my 3 attempts aren't working as expected. (`$DateStartString` I get from row  `$DateStartString = $row['date_start'];`)

```
 echo date_format($row['date_start'],"M/d/YY");
 echo date_format($DateStartString, 'm F Y');
 echo $DateStartString->format('m F Y');
```

Comment: important  missing step if your using date_format `$date=date_create($row['date_start']);`

Comment: ^^ Either do it like Dagon showed it above, or use the OOP style instead: `$dt = new DateTime($row["date_start"]); echo $date->format("m F Y");` (@Dagon btw: you are now in my [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3933332/rizier123?tab=profile) hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @Rizier123 should "done vote for you says spider" ;-)

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/lIcuHD

Comment: try this code:    
    $date = new DateTime($row['date_start']); 
    //d: day, F = Name of Month, Y = Year
    $formatPattern = 'd F Y'; 
    echo $date->format($formatPattern);

See also: http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.format.php

Overview of what else you can use as format pattern:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thank you Dragon and Rizier123. it works perfect - i had to add time zone out of interest which i did not have. is that a security risk or just a essential item to add ?